# += operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload the operator += for the classes gridCoord and genDir in the following code:

```
struct gridCoord{
    unsigned x;
    unsigned y;
}

inline gridCoord operator +(const gridCoord l,const genDir& r){
// This operator is tested and works
}

inline void operator += (gridCoord l,const genDir& r){
    l = l+r;
    std::cout<<l;
}
```

The + operator works, however when I run the below code:

```
int main(){

gridCoord coord(1,0);
genDir gd;

coord += gd;
std::cout<< coord;

std::cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

I get the output

```
x: 2 y: 0
x: 1 y: 0
```

I would expect

```
x: 2 y: 0
x: 2 y: 0
```

If it were working. It seems that the += operator defined doesn't actually modify the left argument as it is supposed to. Any ideas why this is? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know why `void f(int a) { a = 1; } int main() { int x = 0; f(x); cout << x; }` outputs 0? Same thing.

Comment: Everyone is so obsessed with `genDir` nowadays.

Answer (score 6):

To modify `l` you need to pass it by reference:

```
inline void operator += (gridCoord& l,const genDir& r){
                               // ^
```

Otherwise you are only modifying a copy of the passed `gridCoord` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

There two main issues.

For starter you are taking the left hand side argument by value, which means that inside `operator+=`, `l` is simply a copy; therefore any modifications that you are going to perform on this `l` will not be reflected in the original argument on which you called `operator+=` on.

Second, `operator+=` is supposed to return `T&`, which should be a reference to the modified object, to allow chaining.

If you put those together you get something along the lines of:

```
inline gridCoord& operator+=(gridCoord& lhs, genDir const& rhs){
    return lhs = lhs + rhs;
}
```